# C++ program, infinite loop on input

Tags: c++, linux, bash, infinite-loop

Hello i compile this program to an executable called picodb and try to run it through a shell bash script at linux.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Debbuger DB(argc,argv);

    char command[12];
    int len;
    bool valid;

    while(1)
    {
        valid=true;
        cin.clear();
        cin>>command;
        len=strlen(command);
        if(command[0]=='t')
        {
                if(strcmp(command,"trace")==0 || len==1)
                {
                    cin>>command;
                    valid=DB.Trace(command);
                }
                else valid=false;
        }
        else if(command[0]=='r')
        {
            if(strcmp(command,"redirect")==0 || len==1)
             {
                char stream[6],file[15];
                cin>>stream; cin>>file;
                    valid=DB.Redirect(stream,file);
            }
            else valid=false;
        }
       else if(command[0]=='b')
       {
            if(strcmp(command,"blocking-mode")==0 || len==1)
            {
                cin>>command;
                valid=DB.Blocking_mode(command);
            }
            else valid=false;
       }
       else if(command[0]=='l')
       {
           if(strcmp(command,"limit-trace")==0 || len==1)
            {
               int n;
                cin>>n;
                valid=DB.Limit_Trace(n);
           }
            else valid=false;
       }
    else if(command[0]=='g')
    {
           if(strcmp(command,"go")==0 || len==1)
           {
                  DB.Go(argv[1]) ;     


             }
        }


   else if(command[0]=='q')
   {
           if(strcmp(command,"quit")==0 || len==1)
               return 0;
           else
               valid=false;
   }
   else if(command[0]=='h')
   {
           if(strcmp(command,"help")==0 || len==1)
               DB.Help();

           else valid=false;
   }
   else valid =false;

   if(valid==false)
   {
       cout<<"Invalid command"<<endl;
   }


    }
}
```

The script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

./picodb  << EOF
t file_management
r stdin input.txt
EOF
```

but when i execute this script the program goes to an infinite loop where it gets the "t file_management" and never stops or change this input. I printed the string command and it always has the value " t file_management" the first argument. I can't figure what I am doing wrong. I tried running the program at terminal giving it the inputs by hand and works fine.

Edit:To make it clearer this is supposed to be a user interface.It never gets out of loop until you type quit.The problem is that what is read throuth the bash repeats to infinite.

Comment: You don't even have a `break` statement in there...

Comment: @0x499602D2 Why would a break statement be needed? He wants it to continue the loop and read the next line of input.

Comment: @Barmar How is he supposed to get out of the loop if there is no `break`?

Comment: I don't think he's saying that he never gets out of the loop, just that it keeps repeating the first line.

Comment: That said, there's no checking for EOF in the code.

Comment: Your `command` buffer is 12 bytes in size. `"t file_management"` is 17 + 1 bytes in size. A typo? If not how do you see `t file_management` in `command` ?

Comment: It doesn't seem that you're ever skipping past the end of line that terminated the first input.

Comment: @indeterminately sequenced you are right! I dont know how but it worked! I changed it but nothing happened!

Comment: @twalberg i dont exactly understand what you mean.. But how can i do what you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin >> command` will only read one word at a time. Are you sure you have "t file_management" in `command`? When I run your program it works. However it still ran in an infinite loop using the script, so I changed the following line: `while(1)` -> `while(cin >> command)`